# How to Make Fields Required in Edit Form using PreSaveAction

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

How to make a field required on the edit form. It does not appear on the New Form. I can't set it as required at the site column level because the system will not save the New form without that field completed.

I took this PreSaveAction script from another form I have used it with and tried to modify to fix my issue. I installed it as a script editor web part and when I went to the edit page, it triggers the alert, but won't save when I actually fill in the field.

function PreSaveAction(){

```
var Approver Email=  $("select[title$='login']").val();


if(Approver Email!= "" && Approver Email !=undefined ){
    return true;
}
else{
    alert("Please insert your email");
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Your variable name should not have a space. It should be `ApproverEmail`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the `login` field is a People or Group field. Get the value of it in `PreSaveAction` like that

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var dispTitle = "login";      
var pickerDiv = $("[id$='ClientPeoplePicker'][title='" + dispTitle + "']");      
var peoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[pickerDiv.attr("id")];
var userInfo = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
if(userInfo.length > 0){
    console.log(userInfo[0].IsResolved) 

    if(userInfo[0].IsResolved){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        alert("Please insert your email");
        return false;
    }
}
else{
    alert("Please insert your email");
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's not working for some reason on my end Ahmad.

Comment: Do you see any javascript error in console window?

Comment: no because I am using script editor which doesn't show any error